# Should definitions be shown in a list, if not all definitions are available for the list?

Tags: usability, copywriting, readability

So I have a list of terms that all have different definitions, however some of those definitions have not be added to my system for various reasons. There is a debate going on whether it is more beneficial to wait until all definitions are in the system (could be months), or surface the definitions that are already in the system even if a given list would only have definitions for some of the terms.

I can see the argument from both sides, so I am curious if anyone has grappled with the same issue and what the findings were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Incomplete information makes the users anxious

Have a simple query that fetches only those terms that have a corresponding definition. If it is actually a list then you can say, "More definitions coming soon or on their way" at the end to make sure that the users don't think that this is all you have.

There's no point showing terms that don't have any definitions